# Two get parameters rewrite in subfolder

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a site on domain.de/webinterface/.

There is a index.php with two get parameters (page & user)

Now i want that
domain.de/webinterface/user/Niklas redirects to
domain.de/webinterface/index.php?page=user&name=Niklas

I have this atm:

```
location /webinterface/ {
    rewrite ^/webinterface/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /webinterface/index.php?page=$1&name=$2 ;
}
```

But it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me with this qestion?

Comment: That looks OK. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: please add the log

Comment: @MichaelHampton It shows a 404.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
location /webinterface/ {
    rewrite ^/webinterface/(.*)/(.*)$ /webinterface/index.php?page=$1&name=$2 ;
}
```

You can check is everything fine with your rewrite rule with curl:

```
curl -s -D - -o /dev/null domain.de/webinterface/user/Niklas | grep Location
```